# complicated relation fluent nhibernate

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, many-to-many

**hey all**

i'm not sure how to map this.

---

i have got buyer,

buyer can have many buyers.
then i got contract,

now, for each contract the buyer have many different buyers..

```
  public class Buyer
{
    private IList<Buyer> m_buyerList = new List<Buyer>();
    public virtual IList<Buyer> BuyersList
    {
        get { return m_buyerList; }
        set { m_buyerList = value; }
    }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Address { get; set; }
    public virtual string ExtraAddress { get; set; }
    public virtual string PhoneA { get; set; }
    public virtual string PhoneB { get; set; }
    public virtual string PhoneC { get; set; }
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual string Fax { get; set; }
}


public class Contract
    {
        public virtual Buyer MainBuyer { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime SignedDate { get; set; }
    }
```

thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

Buyer mapping:

```
  HasManyToMany(x => x.BuyersList)     
  .ParentKeyColumn("ParentBuyerId")     
  .ChildKeyColumn("BuyerId")
```

Contract mapping:

```
References(x => x.MainBuyer);
```

Comment: that'll make that for every contract, the buyer'll be the father to them.. am i wrong ? i want for each contract the mainbuyer buyers can be different

Comment: Contract mapping will pick its corresponding buyer from the Foreign key. If that buyer has children those will be fetched as well.

Comment: and thats exactly what i dont want to happen. every main buyer buyers depands on contract